# How to override sort method for any column in dgrid (gridFromHtml)?

Tags: sorting, dojo, dgrid

Is there any way to override the sort method and write our own for sorting the particular column in dgrid(gridFromHtml)?

Answer (score 2):

Sorting is done in `_setSort()` of [List.js](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/List.js#L675). It's possible to override, but the underbar is a convention that means "private method."

There's a better (although more complex) method: attach your GridFromHTML to a store sub-classed from `dojo/store/Memory`. Override the Memory store's [`query()` method](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/store/api/Store#query), which accepts [sort parameters](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojo/store/api/Store.QueryOptions) as the 2nd parameter. dGrid will automatically call this method whenever it needs to list/sort data.

Anyways, I generally find the array-backed Grid too limiting and automatically use the store-backed OnDemandGrid.